# Kernel crash when importing R packages to Sypder, rpy2 module, OS X

Tags: python, r, macos, anaconda, rpy2

I have installed rpy2 but I am not able to import any R packages other than those in built ones. Here are more details. My OS is OS X El Capitan. I use anaconda and Spyder 3.2.4, R version 3.4.2. I guess the problem is that the path Spyder refers for libraries is different with the path R libraries are installed. Here is the path info I get from R (RStudio)

```
.libPaths()
"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library"
 R.home()
"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"
```

and the path info I get from Spyder

```
base= rpackages.importr('base')
print(base.R_home())
[1] "/Users/Me/anaconda3/lib/R"
print(base._libPaths())
[1] "/Users/Me/anaconda3/lib/R/library"
```

Here are the codes to install the packages

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
utils = rpackages.importr('utils')

utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1) # select the first mirror in the list
utils.chooseBioCmirror(ind=1) # select the first mirror in the list
packnames = ('e1071')
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector
utils.install_packages(StrVector(packnames))
```

The output is

```
warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/Users/Me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:145: RRuntimeWarning: Making       
'packages.html' ...
 warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
 /Users/Me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-  
 packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:145: RRuntimeWarning:  done

 warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
Out[1]: rpy2.rinterface.NULL
```

When importing the package I get

```
RRuntimeError: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘e1071’
```

I also tried to manually copy and paste the packages from R library to  "/Users/Me/anaconda3/lib/R" but it leads to kernel crashes. I also tried to point rpy2 to R libraries by

```
Forcast=   
rpackages.importr('e1071',lib_loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library")
```

again kernel crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, tried the same things, and had the same kernel crashes. In my case I was trying to import the "forecast" package. I then opened Anaconda-Navigator, installed RStudio from there, and installed the "forecast" package in RStudio. Now I'm able to import the package in Python.